# Div not working on this specific document

Tags: html, css, image

I've been messing around with images sliding with hover on a separate page from my main work and it worked like a charm. However, when I transfer it to my main page, it doesn't work, for some reason. I even copy-and-pasted so there should be absolutely no problem going on.

```
.pictureContainer2 img:hover {
    top: 50px;
       }
.pictureContainer2 img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    transition: top .2s ease-in-out; }
```

And this is how it is in the body.

```
<div class="pictureContainer2">
<a href="#"><img src="icontag.png"></a></div>
```

I'm sorry if this is obvious or just plain silly. I just got into web development.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Is the image not showing up?  Can you describe the symptoms?  Are you sure the image path is the same?

Comment: Can you share the result? Full code?

Comment: I'm not sure why you aren't getting any response, but I would put the hover on the container so its less glitchy: `.pictureContainer2:hover img` http://jsfiddle.net/gLcjarn4/

Comment: The code you have works. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/181opdfc/)

Comment: @dwreck08 Because you can't find the solution if you don't know the problem. It's not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not specifying! The image is indeed showing up, but it's not working when I move my mouse over it.

Comment: @IsabelaSantos Is it not moving it down when you hover over it? From what I've seen it seems to be working in the above fiddles. Try clearing the cache, it might still be loading the old page.

Comment: I tried to insert a style inside the <img> like this `<img src="icontag2.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; transition: top .2s ease-in-out;">` and it seems to have worked. But now I don't know if it's possible to do the same with hover?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes, it's not moving down when I hover over it. My code is a bit large so I don't know exactly how to reproduce it. I already did all of those things and still nothing...

Comment: Well, I found out why it's not working... It's because there is a CSS slideshow on the code. I decided to remove it and now it works.